# Cronjob not running correctly

Tags: bash, backup, cron

I have a prepared a script which will run a backup of my postgreSQL database using pgbackrest and then push it to Backblaze B2 using restic. Unfortunately it won't execute and show me no error in the syslog.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dayofweek=`date +"%a"`
timeofday=`date +"%k"`

if [[ $(id -u) -ne 112 ]] ; then echo "Please run as user postgres" ; exit 1 ; fi

if [ $dayofmonth == "Sun" && $timeofday == 1 ];
then
echo "running weekly backup";
pgbackrest --stanza=sonar --type=full backup;
B2_ACCOUNT_ID="ID" B2_ACCOUNT_KEY="KEY" restic -r b2:sonar-pg backup /var/lib/pg-backup/backup/sonar --password-file /restic-pw.txt;
else
echo "running daily";
pgbackrest --stanza=sonar backup;
B2_ACCOUNT_ID="ID" B2_ACCOUNT_KEY="KEY" restic -r b2:sonar-pg backup /var/lib/pg-backup/backup/sonar --password-file /restic-pw.txt;
fi
```

It runs perfectly fine when running manually in the console with:

```
sudo su -ui postgres /var/lib/pg-backup/backup.sh
```

When running as a cronjob (in crontab):

```
15 * * * * postgres bash /var/lib/pg-backup/backup.sh
```

I have tried appending > /tmp/backup.log but no logs have been written.

How can I troubleshoot this in a better way or solve the issue?

Edit:
Solution: Put the crontab entry in the /etc/crontab file

Comment: Since no output is generated, it might not start the cron-job at all? Look in /var/log/syslog  for cron messages around minute 15 every hour. Maybe the `postgres` command needs full path.

Comment: postgres is the user it is executed with, not the command. the command is bash /var/...

Comment: In what crontab file ? Normally you edit a users crontab with `crontab -e` and there are no user in the crontab line ...

Comment: I have tried sudo crontab -u postgres -e as well and it did not work

Comment: Did you check /var/log/syslog ?

Comment: May  6 11:50:01 sonar CRON[97522]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /var/lib/pg-backup/back
up.sh >> /tmp/backup.log 2>&1)
May  6 11:50:01 sonar CRON[97521]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding out
put)

Comment: So it did run. Did it output anything to /tmp/backup.log ? If not, try adding an "echo something" as the first statement in the script so we have some unconditional output, and maybe a `set -x` for full debug. This should output to stdout/stderr and thereby to /tmp/backup.log because of the redirection.

Comment: I have tested when it outputs something, the only output I get is when it is run as root and it write "Please run as user postgres". It seems that it does not work correctly when running as another user. I have tried runuser -l postgres -c '...' as root, which does not seem to work

Comment: Use the systemwide `/etc/cronbtab` (or a file in `/etc/cron.d`) which has an additional field to specify the user explicitly.

Comment: what steeldriver suggested worked - no idea why it would not when using the users crontab

Comment: @Timo because user crontab does not have a 'user' field.